# Offline app in asp.net

Tags: html, caching, offline-caching, cache-manifest

I am trying create an app which has offline features. The manifest file that I have created looks like this-

```
CACHE MANIFEST 
# version 1.0.0

CACHE:
/ShareBill.Web-Offline/
/ShareBill.Web-Offline/Groups
/ShareBill.Web-Offline/Content/Site.css
/ShareBill.Web-Offline/Content/jquery-ui.css
/ShareBill.Web-Offline/Scripts/ShareBill.js
/ShareBill.Web-Offline/Scripts/lib/jquery-1.7.2.min.js
/ShareBill.Web-Offline/Scripts/lib/jquery-ui.min.js
/ShareBill.Web-Offline/Scripts/TransactionsIndex.js
/ShareBill.Web-Offline/Content/Images/ajax-loader.gif
/ShareBill.Web-Offline/Content/Images/br_down_icon.png

NETWORK: 
/ShareBill.Web-Offline/Transactions/Filters
```

What I expect is when I view this url     /ShareBill.Web-Offline/Groups. My browser should not make any requests to the server else the whole purpose of being offline would be void.

But as I can observe using fiddler is that, the browser makes a request for the manifest file every time i refresh the page. I made sure that I see the cached resources in the Chrome dev tools.

Now when I turn my IIS off and make a request like this, I end making my AppCache status as OBSOLETE. Then on the very next page refresh, I get a 404 response. Am I missing something in terms of implementation?

Comment: The AppCache should only be set to `OBSOLETE` if the request receives a 404 or 410 response, your server would need to be running for the browser to receive such a response.  If the server is not running, the browser would receive no response at all.

Answer (score 0):

I applied the Expires header to request that was asking for the Manifest file. And that worked :)

Comment: What expires header did you apply?  The app is supposed to request the manifest file every time so that it can find out whether or not there's been an update.

Comment: I added an Expires date of 2050-01-01 (yyyy-mm-dd). This in essence would make no requests at all to the server. There is still a problem, I need to purge the application cache when the file any js file at the server end is updated. Even though I update my manifest file, I will not get those changes on the client since the manifest file it self is cached.

Comment: If your manifest file never expires then your appcache will never be updated, that's why the browser is checking the manifest file every time.